# Using logical functions on grouping in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, pivot

Is there a way to evaluate OR or AND logic functions using a group in t-SQL?

```
DECLARE @TimeClock TABLE 
                   (
                       EName  NVARCHAR(14),
                       Time   NVARCHAR(5),
                       OnTime TINYINT
                   )
    
INSERT INTO @TimeClock VALUES ('Adam', '07:55', 1)
INSERT INTO @TimeClock VALUES ('Adam', '08:03', 0)
INSERT INTO @TimeClock VALUES ('Bob',  '07:57', 1)
INSERT INTO @TimeClock VALUES ('Bob',  '07:59', 1)
INSERT INTO @TimeClock VALUES ('Carl', '08:01', 0)
INSERT INTO @TimeClock VALUES ('Carl', '08:02', 0)

SELECT    
    EName,
    OR(OnTime) AS SometimesLate,
    AND(OnTime) AS AlwaysLate,
    NOT(OR(OnTime)) AS NeverLate
FROM 
    @TimeClock
GROUP BY 
    EName
```

I could do it like this for a very simple case:

```
SELECT    
    tc.EName,
    IIF(n.EName IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS SometimesLate,
    IIF(o.EName IS NULL, 1, 0) AS AlwaysLate,
    IIF(n.EName IS NULL, 1, 0) AS NeverLate
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT EName FROM @TimeClock) tc
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT EName FROM @TimeClock WHERE OnTime = 1) o ON o.EName = tc.EName
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT EName FROM @TimeClock WHERE OnTime = 0) n ON n.EName = tc.EName
```

But if I had a lot of different columns (e.g., OnTime, 5 minutes late, 10 minutes late, etc.) that becomes pretty intensive.

[image]

Comment: Aside: There are various tricks using [`Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for implementing logic that can be combined with aggregation. Masked bits can be reduced to `1`/`0` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949762/92546) answer. To `or` bits use `Sign( B1 + B2 + ... )`. (`And` is simply `B1 * B2 * ...`.) A more fiendish example of arithmetic logic is used in a CTE in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944142/92546) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some databases have boolean aggregation functions (such as Postgres), but SQL Server is not one of them.

However, no need for that complicated logic here. We can emulate boolean aggregation with `MIN()`, `MAX()`, and basic arithmetics, like so:

```
select    
    ename,
    1 - min(ontime) as sometimeslate,
    1 - max(ontime) as alwayslate,
    min(ontime) as neverlate
from @timeclock
group by ename
```

Comment: Okay, that's just brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: Also, looking at all the possibilities, I now see MAX(ontime) as sometimesontime